# How to show exact match (either word or sentence) result first and then others in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi is any query in the elastic search which will display exact match (either word or sentence) results first and then partial match results.please help me into this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-match queries and boost exact matches. Chech https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: Can you please give me any example of such query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a match query as follows.
Suppose you are looking for a word "tim"

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [{"match": {"field_name": "tim"}}
]
}
}
}
```

This will automatically return the best results first, and for partial matches, you can read on fuzzy queries:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to search "This is the demo" phrase or sentence then how I can use above query?please help me

Comment: If you put "This is the demo" inside the `should` clause and use match, you will get back hits for "this" "is" "the" "demo", if your index is set to `not_analyzed`. if you want to match the whole phrase, use `match_phrase` in your clause. You can use `must` or `should` depending on your requirement. You can decide that by taking a look at this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html